# How to change name of fields when serialized exposed fields using Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using Gson to serialize a Java object and return a json string. The object has many fields, but I'm trying to return 4 in particular. I'm using the @Expose annotation to tell Gson to ignore any other fields, but I would also like to be able to change the name of these fields to be returned. Using GsonBuilder this way

```
Gson gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().setPrettyPrinting().create();
```

I am able to only get only fields with `@Expose`. Is there a way to use `@SerializedName` along with `@Expose`, to change the name of these fields before they are returned? Using both annotations blocks anything from being returned, but I'm also finding that using just the `@SerializedName` annotation (and removing `.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()`) also prevents those fields from being returned.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.
Here's a working example:

```
package test;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class MyData {
  @Expose
  private String id;

  @Expose
  @SerializedName("fileOriginalName")
  private String myFilename;

  @Expose
  @SerializedName("fileOriginalPath")
  private String myPath;

  private String myName;

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getMyFilename() {
    return myFilename;
  }

  public void setMyFilename(String myFilename) {
    this.myFilename = myFilename;
  }

  public String getMyPath() {
    return myPath;
  }

  public void setMyPath(String myPath) {
    this.myPath = myPath;
  }

  public String getMyName() {
    return myName;
  }

  public void setMyName(String myName) {
    this.myName = myName;
  }

}
```

And the caller:

```
package test;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class Demo {
  static final Type MYDATA_TYPE = new TypeToken<MyData>() {
  }.getType();
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    MyData d = new MyData();

    d.setId("10");
    d.setMyFilename("was called myFilename");
    d.setMyName("should not be visible");
    d.setMyPath("was called myPath");

    String json = gson.toJson(d, MYDATA_TYPE);
    System.out.println(json);
  }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
{
  "id": "10",
  "fileOriginalName": "was called myFilename",
  "fileOriginalPath": "was called myPath"
}
```

Comment: `@SerializedName` prevents whatever it is on from being returned - Everything without it returns fine.

Comment: Do you mean that when you run the example above you get different output?

Comment: Your example works for me. For my project, I'm first first deserializing a json file to the object I'm using. I'm doing this to be able to change the names of certain fields before I return them. Most examples I see use `@SerializedName` are setting their field values in the code. Could this discrepancy be the cause of my `@SerializedName` fields not being returned?